# DFS tree traversal function modification

Tags: java, tree, traversal, depth-first-search

Please find below my implementation for DFS.

```
protected void DFS(String search) {
    for(Tree<T> child : leafs) {
        if(child.value.equals(search))
            return;
        else 
            child.DFS(search);            
        System.out.println(child.value);     
    }
}
```

The objective is to stop traversal on finding the node whose value is in the variable search. However, the above function goes on traversing the tree even beyond the declared search node. Could someone help me modify the above function?

Thank you.

---

Edit 1

```
protected boolean DFS(String anaphorKey) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(Tree<T> child : leafs) {
        if(child.head.equals(anaphorKey))
            return true;
        found = child.DFS(anaphorKey);
        if(found == true)
            break;            
        System.out.println(child.head);     
        //System.out.println("anaphorKey: "+anaphorKey);
    }
    return found;
}
```

Tried implementing the given answer suggestion (@SJuan76). The implementation above isn't working as desired. Could you point me to the place where code is not as per the logic suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rookie, might I suggest an implementation using the classic for-loop (as opposed to the enhanced for-loop being used now) which allows integration of your stop-condition a bit better, something like:

```
protected boolean DFS(String key) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < leafs.size() && !found; i++) {
        Tree<T> child = leafs.get(i);

        if(child.head.equals(key))
            found = true;
        else
            found = child.DFS(key);
    }

    return found;
}
```

So as soon as your found condition is hit, the 'found' becomes true and your loop stops.

What you may have forgotten is the "found = child.DFS(key)" portion of the recursion, where you need to remember the result of your recursive calls so ALL your for-loops on up the chain all break as soon as you return.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I plugged in your function into my program, but it still isn't working. According to the logic it clearly should. The control isn't entering the if(child.head.equals(key)) conditional. The key is certainly in the tree. Would it be a casting error?

Comment: resolved! yes, a casting statment was needed between Generic and String.

Comment: NOTE: The trick that Riyad pointed out is that the loop has to check in every iteration if a correct node has been found!

Answer (score 1):

Option A (Nice): the function returns a value, when the node is found it returns a different value that if the node was not found. When you call to method, if you get the `found` value you stop the loop and return the `found` value too.

Option B (Ugly): When found, thow an Exception (better if it is your own implementation of it). Don't forget to catch it.

Option C (Uglier): The same with global (static) variables.

UPDATE 1:

It looks like your method should run ok now, can you check (`System.out.println`) if your value is ever found?

In a more personal opinion, I would find

```
protected boolean DFS(String anaphorKey) { 
  for(Tree<T> child : leafs) { 
    if(child.head.equals(anaphorKey)) 
      return true; 
    if(child.DFS(anaphorKey))  // No need to store value. No need to check == true (it is implicit)
      return true;             // If we are in this line the value was found, always return true
    System.out.println(child.head);      
    //System.out.println("anaphorKey: "+anaphorKey); 
  } 
  return false;  // If the method did not exit previously it was because the value was not found, so in this line always return false
}
```

more readable (but it should work exactly as your implementation)

Comment: Please see Edit1 above; need guidance.

Comment: Yes, it does stop search when the node is found. The suggestion offered by [Riyad] does trace back from the found node through the parents also; the one which I implemented based on my understanding of your suggestion does not trace back through the parents of the search node.